# GWT onSubmitComplete not fired in firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, gwt

The `onSubmitComplete()` is being fired in IE and Chrome but not firefox.

I've already set the content type to text/html:

```
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

And when looking into firefox network console I got this as the response:

```
<p>The specified account hasn't been activated yet</p>
```

but the event isn't fired.

I don't generate any of the page html using gwt, instead I wrap the elements:

```
private void wrapForm()
{
    this.form = FormPanel.wrap(DOM.getElementById("form"),true);
    form.addSubmitHandler(this);
    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(this);
}
```

The `onSubmitComplete()` is as follows:

```
public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
{
    console.debug("Run");
    removeLoader(submitLoader);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the doco for `FormPanel` a key to getting the `SubmitCompleteEvent`s is the creation of generated `target` attribute in the form element being wrapped. It'd be interesting to know that once the module loads - but before the form submits - can you you inspect the form element and compare the `target` attribute between the browsers? ... discrepancy between the browsers suggests a bug, but tracing what's happening behind the scenes may give some clues to a work-around.

Comment: The response to the form actually goes into the <iframe> used to hold it in every browser (including FireFox) but still the SubmitCompleteEvent is not triggered